# Php Javascript : Keeping radio buttons selected on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have responsive css tabs I use to display information in an elegant manner but when user refresh page it goes back to first checked input. I would like to know how to keep the user button selected on page refresh the one who he previously selected. I wrote a script but it does not seem to work.

**tabs**

```
  <input class="inputabs" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked">
  <label class="labeltabs" for="tab1">Inbox</label>

  <input class="inputabs" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" >
  <label class="labeltabs"for="tab2">Important</label>

  <input class="inputabs" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label class="labeltabs" for="tab3">Bin</label>
```

**script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputabs input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr("checked",$(this).checked());
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: You will have to pass information upon the page refresh or use some sort of storage otherwise when the page reloads any changes via javascript will be lost.

Comment: @NewToJS: do you mind teaching by example? `:-D`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will the following work for you requirement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if(localStorage.selected) {
        $('#' + localStorage.selected ).attr('checked', true);
      }
      $('.inputabs').click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem("selected", this.id);
      });
    });

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input class="inputabs" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked">
  <label class="labeltabs" for="tab1">Inbox</label>

  <input class="inputabs" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" >
  <label class="labeltabs"for="tab2">Important</label>

  <input class="inputabs" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label class="labeltabs" for="tab3">Bin</label>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Correct answer. Please choose this as solution so that it would help future users. FYI, to see the data stored in local storage, In chrome -> press F12 ->click Application -> Choose local storage on side nav. You will find the key and value as "selected" and "tab2" which helps to store the value entered by user.